# Redirecting legacy routes presents mapper error with rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, routes, rake

routes.rb:

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "posts#index"
  match "posts/autocomplete_topic_name", :as => "autocomplete_topic_name"
  match "/new" => "posts#new", :as => :new
  # resources
  resources :topics
  resources :posts
  resources :comments
  # static
  match "/about"   => "pages#about",   :as => :about
  match "/help"    => "pages#help",    :as => :help
  match "/home"    => "home#index",    :as => :home
  # redirects
  match "/tags" => redirect("/topics")
  match "/entries" => redirect("/posts")
  match "/comments" => redirect("/")
end
```

At the end of `rake routes` the error reads:

```
              tags        /tags(.:format)                          {:to=>#<Proc:0x00000001485d18@/home/basicobject/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:366 (lambda)>}
            entries        /entries(.:format)                       {:to=>#<Proc:0x0000000133d438@/home/basicobject/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:366 (lambda)>}
                           /comments(.:format)                      {:to=>#<Proc:0x000000012e8708@/home/basicobject/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:366 (lambda)>}
```

I'm trying to redirect some legacy routes to the new routes for better SEO. Routes like:

`/entries/8` need to be redirected to `/posts/8` et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

Stick this in your `application_controller.rb`

```
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError do |exception|
  flash[:error] = "Sorry, we were not quite sure where you were trying to go"
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Comment: Would it be better to display a 404 instead of redirecting to root? PS: thank you for your response. My next step was to create a catch all route for all other routing errors.

Comment: The author of this question is wanting to preserve legacy URL's. Throwing 404's will to little for SEO as will redirecting to root.  What you need to be doing is returning 301's with the new URL. When google encounters 301's it will update it's index. Anything else can lower your SEO ranking for given content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to preserve the full url and pass it along with any parameters. In this case not even a wild card match will do as you will not be able to pass it to the new route.

Try this

```
match "/entries/:post_id" => redirect("/posts/%{post_id}")
```

That will pass your param as well as throwing the correct HTTP error code so google will update it's index.